# PHP - Display results from MySQL correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I was just wondering if there is a way to display this one after the other rather than first amounts than dates.

```
$apaidString = $apaid;
$daterString = $dater;
$apaidArray = explode(',', $apaidString);
$daterArray = explode(',', $daterString);

<?php foreach($apaidArray as $apaid_Array){
echo trim($apaid_Array,",").'<br>';}?>
<?php foreach($daterArray as $dater_Array){
echo trim($dater_Array,",").'<br>';}?>
```

This code will display:

```
50
60
10
11-11-2016
12-11-2016
14-11-2016
```

What i would need would be:

```
50 11-11-2016
60 12-11-2016
10 14-11-2016
```

I get the values from a MySQL.

Comment: Why playing ping pong with the variables?

Comment: @Cluster  you need only one loop to do this.Its same as triangle pattern logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk both arrays at the same time :

```
<?php
$apaidString = "50,60,10";
$daterString = "11-11-2016,12-11-2016,14-11-2016";
$apaidArray = explode(',', $apaidString);
$daterArray = explode(',', $daterString);

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($apaidArray); $i++ )
{ echo $apaidArray[$i].'<br>';
  echo $daterArray[$i].'<br>';
}
?>
```

The result is:

```
50
11-11-2016
60
12-11-2016
10
14-11-2016
```

Comment: You don't want count() within the loop ;)

Comment: Why count() should not be within the loop?

Comment: @Cluster, did you test my answer? It works great, it is what you need, just look at the result.

Comment: @bub, would you explain your comment? Cluster won't accept my answer because of your comment (and my answer works perfectly).

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez oh your answer is fine, I just mentioned the count in the loop(). Do something like $count = count(...)

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do like this but i'm not sure that is the better way

```
foreach($apaidArray as $key_array => $apaid_Array)
{
    echo trim($apaid_Array,",").' '.trim($daterArray[$key_array],",") .'</br>';
}
```

output:

```
50 11-11-2016
60 12-11-2016
10 14-11-2016
```

instead of

```
foreach($apaidArray as $apaid_Array){
echo trim($apaid_Array,",").'<br>';}
foreach($daterArray as $dater_Array){
echo trim($dater_Array,",").'<br>';}
```

and you can do directly

```
$apaidArray = explode(',', $apaid);
$daterArray = explode(',', $dater);
```

instead of

```
$apaidString = $apaid;
$daterString = $dater;
$apaidArray = explode(',', $apaidString);
$daterArray = explode(',', $daterString);
```

Comment: I got that before posting but still no joy.